# error while creating new project with Angular-cli

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu-14.04, angular-cli

When I am trying to create new project by using the command, **ng new project-name**, I am getting error like below:

> fs.js:640
>    return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
>                    ^
>
> TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
>       at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
>       at Function.Version.fromProject (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:87:31)
>       at Function.Version.isPreWebpack (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:111:31)
>       at Function.Version.assertPostWebpackVersion (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:97:18)
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:25:15
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
>       at ondir (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:187:31)
>       at /usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:153:39

- ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
- node 6.6.0
- npm 3.9.5
- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.14

I suspect some issues while installing angular-cli but I am not sure. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: After so many trial and errors, It got resolved. :)

Comment: Could you share how it was resolved? I had a similar issue

Comment: I wish there was exact solution but i did trial and error. 
`sudo npm uninstall angular-cli -g`
`sudo npm cache clean`
`sudo apt-get remove nodejs`

restart the machine.

then **install nodejs(latest), then install angular-cli**

Comment: I have this problem, too. Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 with node v6.6.0 + npm 3.10.3. No solution found yet.

Comment: Then you can upvote the question. Some one can help you :) btw what is the issue for you? is it same? If so did you try what I have suggested in above comments?

Comment: I get the same error message after typing anything with ng...

Comment: ok try what I have suggested and let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: I did: `sudo npm uninstall angular-cli -g` `sudo npm cache clean` `sudo npm uninstall angular-cli -g`  `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -` `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` `sudo npm install -g angular-cli` and still the same error

Comment: Even though this is stupidest idea, once again uninstall them and run sudo apt-get update and restart the machine. then try again. Even I am not sure what and how i solved it. I tried for some hours to resolve it. then i gave up. tried next day. it worked. may be my luck or some issue with npm package servers. not sure.

Comment: Please post your issue on github and look at this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2216

Comment: Restart the machine after uninstall angular-cli has no positive effect... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and this post was helpful: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2135

It's maybe a little too hacky to really recommend as a solution, but this answer at least got me going:

> Simplest workaround to continue working in your project is comment line 25 of node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng :
>   // Version.assertPostWebpackVersion();
>   Until it is fixed properly.

Comment: Should `npm install -g webpack` also be a solution?

Comment: Just doing npm-install -g webpack didn't do it for me, had to go with commenting out line 25. That got me up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue was able to fix it by doing the below:

```
  npm uninstall -g angular-cli
  npm cache clean
  npm install -g node-gyp
  npm install -g angular-cli
```

Then do ng --version to see if installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `npm install -g webpack` before `npm install -g angular-cli`