# Can not install angular-cli on mac Elcapitan

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, angular-cli

when I try to install angular-cli I see so many warnings and after this when i type

ng --version it shows :

MDSAZIDs-iMac:~ MYMAC$ ng --version

fs.js:640
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer

```
at TypeError (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
at Function.Version.fromProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:87:31)
at Function.Version.isPreWebpack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:111:31)
at Function.Version.assertPostWebpackVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:97:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:25:15
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
at ondir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:187:31)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:153:39
```

MDSAZIDs-iMac:~ MYMAC$

I dont what is the problem can anyone tell me..????

Comment: did you try to install it with sudo?

Comment: @galvan yes i did ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in many ways but nothing was working for me then i installed windows 7 in a vertual machine and then installed latest nodejs on that windows 7 .then through npm I installed angular-cli and every thing is working well on that windows 7 :)

Upadate:
I have found this tutorial which has totaly solved my problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mtlrXYKsZ0&index=1&list=PLrMggSuNOco6iLjrCOsO1_UKmJQosr7_g

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar to the issue on ubuntu.

[error while creating new project with Angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541930/error-while-creating-new-project-with-angular-cli/39660270#39660270)

Can you post this issue on github? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues

Edit:
can you try to use `npm install -g webpack` before installing angular-cli. (as sudo/root please)

This fixed my problem! :)

Comment: sebge23  yeah this problem is showing up in ubuntu too.... I am searching for the solution but have not any clue at all.... :(

Comment: i have done that but still the same problem :(
my npm version is 3.10.3
  node version is 6.6.0

Comment: Did you uninstall and reinstall angular-cli? Or alternatively,  you can use `npm update -g angular-cli`

Comment: I tried everything i could but not working....so I am working with the old way.... by not using the cli... thanks for helping.......